# SQL - How many numbers from 1 list are in another list

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a SQL query question.
I am write a smal lotto program in .net with a SQL backend.

the simple description of my problem is this:
i have a set of numbers (5 or 6) of the game which was drawn and a table full with suggested games (can be between a few thousand to a million).

i basically want to end up with that suggestion table updated with what the potential win would have been for each suggested game.

```
suggested game 1: 3 numbers correct
suggested game 2: 0 numbers correct
suggested game 3: 6 numbers correct
...
```

because of the potential size of the suggestion table speed is of essence.

the below is the direction i was going, but i am stuck and also don't think its going the right direction.

```
declare @WinningGame table(n1 int)
insert into @WinningGame (n1) values (5)
insert into @WinningGame (n1) values (12)
insert into @WinningGame (n1) values (15)
insert into @WinningGame (n1) values (16)
insert into @WinningGame (n1) values (22)
insert into @WinningGame (n1) values (35)


declare @SuggestedGames table(
N1 int,
N2 int,
N3 int,
N4 int,
N5 int,
N6 int,
Hit1 int,
Hit2 int,
Hit3 int,
Hit4 int,
Hit5 int,
Hit6 int)

insert into @SuggestedGames
(N1, N2, N3, N4, N5, N6, Hit1, Hit2, Hit3, Hit4, Hit5, Hit6)
Values (5, 12, 15, 16, 22, 35, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
(5, 12, 16, 18, 27, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
(5, 12, 15, 16, 22, 35, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

select (case when N1 in (select * from @WinningGame) then 1 else 0 end) as myCount
from @SuggestedGames
```

thoughts, help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a left join of `@SuggestedGames` to `@WinningGame` and aggregation:

```
select s.N1, s.N2, s.N3, s.N4, s.N5, s.N6,
       count(w.n1) as myCount
from @SuggestedGames s left join @WinningGame w
on w.n1 in (s.N1, s.N2, s.N3, s.N4, s.N5, s.N6)
group by s.N1, s.N2, s.N3, s.N4, s.N5, s.N6
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your quick reply. unfortunately it does not provide the correct result. it returns for the 1st suggested game a result of 13. it should be 6, all 6 suggested numbers are in the drawn game.

Comment: @Gunnar Your sample data contain 2 rows that are the same. I guess this is not right. This is why you get these results. Try it with different suggested rows.

Comment: Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=befc67863611b52dd8712bceab004128

Comment: Nice catch!!!!!!!!!!! - yup - now it looks correct!. Nice - thank you very much. i'll run it tonight against a large live table and see how performance looks like. Thanks again for your help!.

Comment: It would be better if you define a composite primary key in SuggestedGames for the columns N1, N2, N3, N4, N5, N6

Comment: i can probably do that - i might do it after a 1st test, then re-run to see improvement. Thanks for all your help and suggestions